# Reducing Time Complexity of these two methods?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
/*
 * Returns true if this and other are rankings of the same
 * set of strings; otherwise, returns false. Throws a
 * NullPointerException if other is null. Must run in O(n)
 * time, where n is the number of elements in this (or other).
 */
public boolean sameNames(Ranking other)
{
    ArrayList<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> str2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.getNumItems(); i++){
        str1.add(this.getStringOfRank(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < other.getNumItems(); i++){
        str2.add(other.getStringOfRank(i));
    }
    Collections.sort(str1);
    Collections.sort(str2);
    if(str1.size() == str2.size())
        return str1.containsAll(str2);
    else
        return false;
}
```

Ok so in the code above, using str1.containsAll(str2) destroys my O(n) time complexity, as I believe it is O(n^2) in this case. My question how can I compare the contents of two arrays/arrayLists without using O(n^2). All I can think of is nested for loop, which of course is O(n^2).

```
/*
 * Returns the rank of name. Throws an IllegalArgumentException
 * if name is not present in the ranking. Must run in O(log n)
 * time, where n = this.getNumItems().
 */
public int getRankOfString(String name)
{       
    Cities[] nameTest = new Cities[city.length];
    int min = 0;
    int max = city.length;
    System.arraycopy(city, 0, nameTest, 0, city.length);
    Arrays.sort(nameTest, Cities.BY_NAME);
    while(max >= min){
        int mid = (min + max)/2;
        if(nameTest[mid].getName().equals(name))
            return nameTest[mid].getRank();
        else if(nameTest[mid].getName().compareTo(name) < 0)
            min = mid + 1;
        else
            max = mid-1;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

And this one, this has to be O(log n). So I used a binary search, however it only works on sorted arrays, so I have to call Arrays.sort(), BUT I can't mess with the order of the actual array so I have to copy the array using System.arraycopy(). This is most likely O(n + (n log n) + log n), which is not log n. I don't know what other way I can search for something, it seems like log n is the best, but that is binary search and would force me to sort array first, which just adds time...

P.S. I am not allowed to use Maps or Sets... :(

Any help would be awesome.

Sorry, a ranking object contains an array of city names that can be called and an array of rankings (just ints) for each city that can be called. sameNames() is simply testing two ranking objects possess the same cities, getRankofString() has a set name entered, it then checks to see if that name is in the ranking object, if it is, it returns its corresponding rank. Hope that cleared it up

And yeah, cannot use hash anything. We are basically limited to messing around with arrays and arrayLists and stuff.

Comment: You didn't say what the functions are supposed to do. There are comments, but they aren't very helpful because they refer to a concept of "rankings of strings" which wasn't explained.

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the occurrences of each string. It's a bit similar to the [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

1. Create a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) `t` with hashing function `f()`, where keys are strings and values are integers (initially 0).
2. Iterate through the first strings, for each string do `t[f(string)]++`.
3. Iterate through the second strings, for each string do `t[f(string)]++`.
4. Iterate through the non-zero values in `t`, if all are even - return true. Otherwise - false.

Linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The first method has complexity at least `O(n^2)`, given by `2*O(n*f(n)) + 2*O(n log n) + O(n^2)`. The `O(n log n)` is given by the `Collections.sort()` calls which will also 'destroys your `O(n)`' complexity as you put it.

Since both array lists are already sorted and of equal length when you try `containsAll`, that call is equivalent with some sort of equals (first element in one list should be equal to the first element in the second one, etc). You can easily compare the two lists manually (can't think of any build-in function that does this).

Hence, the overall complexity of the first piece of code can be reduced to O(n log n), if you can keep the complexity of `getStringOfRank()` under `O(log n)` (but ***that*** function is not shown in your post).

---

The second function (which isn't related to the first piece of code) has the complexity O(n log n) as pointed out by your computations. If you already copy, then sort the city array, the binary search is pointless. Don't copy, don't sort, just compare each city in the array, putting the entire complexity of this function to `O(n)`. Alternatively, just keep a sorted copy of the `city` array and use binary search on that.

Either way, creating a copy of an array, sorting that copy for each function call is **highly** ineffective - if you want to call this function inside a loop, like you used `getStringOfRank()` above, construct the sorted copy before the loop and use it as an argument:

```
private boolean getRankOfString(String name, Cities[] sortedCities) {
    // only binary search code needed here
}
```

---

*Off-topic*:

Based on the second function, you have something like `Cities[] city` declared in somewhere your code. If it were to follow conventions, it should be more like `City[] cities` (class name singular, array name should be the one using the plural)

Comment: Actually getStringofRank() is O(1) time. But I copied the array and sorted it inside getRankofString() because I need to sort the names of the cities, but can't actually sort the real array of names, thus a copy is needed. They are unsorted originally and must stay that way. And it is required of me to have log n time for the getRankOfString(), so O(n) would be too high, thus I used the binary search instead of just a simple search through.

Answer (score 0):

So the first one just needs to compare if the two have the exact same names and nothing else?

How about this

```
public static boolean compare(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
  if (l1.size() != l2.size()) return false;
  long hash1 = 0;
  long hash2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < l1.size() ; i++) {
    hash1 += l1.get(i).hashCode();
    hash2 += l2.get(i).hashCode();
  }
  return hash1 == hash2;
}
```

In theory, you could get a hash collision I suppose.

Comment: Can't use anything related to hashes... But what I did was create a copied array in the constructor then sorted that copied array to use in different methods. My constructor was O(n log n), then the copy is +O(n) then the sort is another +O(n log n), so in the end my constructor should still be O(n log n) (which it has to be... :P). But this allowed me to utilize O(log n) binary search as well as O(n) sameName() test.